# Node.js websocket.io cursor example I couldn't see it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm new to node.js and working my way through examples of the 'smashing node.js' book. In the websockets chapter I'm struggling to get this example to work. Forgive me it's a really simple error! I'm confused that why couldn't I see the cursor even using the author's code? And I downloaded the source code from Github.

Code is below: (firstly `server.js` file):

```
var express = require('express')
  , wsio = require('websocket.io')

/**
 * Create express app.
 */

var app = express.createServer();

/**
 * Attach websocket server.
 */

var ws = wsio.attach(app);

/**
 * Serve our code
 */

app.use(express.static('public'))

/**
 * Listening on connections
 */

var positions = {}
  , total = 0

ws.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // we give the socket an id
  socket.id = ++total;

  // we send the positions of everyone else
  socket.send(JSON.stringify(positions));

  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    try {
      var pos = JSON.parse(msg);
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    }

    positions[socket.id] = pos;
    broadcast(JSON.stringify({ type: 'position', pos: pos, id: socket.id }));
  });

  socket.on('close', function () {
    delete positions[socket.id];
    broadcast(JSON.stringify({ type: 'disconnect', id: socket.id }));
  });

  function broadcast (msg) {
    for (var i = 0, l = ws.clients; i < l; i++) {
      // we avoid sending a message to the same socket that broadcasts
      if (socket.id != ws.clients[i].id) {
        // we call `send` on the other clients
        ws.clients[i].send(msg);
      }
    }
  }
});

/**
 * Listen
 */

app.listen(3000);
```

Secondly the script contents of the `./public/index.html` file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebSocket cursors</title>
    <script src="onload">
      window.onload = function () {
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

        ws.onopen = function () {
          document.onmousemove = function (ev) {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({ x: ev.clientX, y: ev.clientY }));
          }
        }

        ws.onmessage = function (msg) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(msg);

          // the first message is the position of all existing cursors
          if (initialized) {
            initialized = true;
            for (var id in obj) {
              move(id, obj[i]);
            }
          } else {
            // other messages can either be a position change or
            // a disconnection
            if ('disconnect' == obj.type) {
              remove(obj.id);
            } else {
              move(obj.id, obj.pos);
            }
          }
        }

        function move (id, pos) {
          var cursor = document.getElementById('cursor-' + id);

          if (!cursor) {
            cursor = document.createElement('img');
            cursor.src = '/cursor.png';
            cursor.style.position = 'absolute';
            document.body.appendChild(cursor);
          }

          cursor.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
          cursor.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
        }

        function remove (id) {
          var cursor = document.getElementById('cursor-' + id);
          cursor.parentNode.removeChild(cursor);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>WebSocket cursors</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the express framework from version 2.x.x to the newest version and I updated my websocket.io. Then Rewrited my codes. Now I can run it successfully.
Here's my codes:

server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    wsio = require('websocket.io'),
    port = 3000,
    app = express(),
    server = app.listen(port, function() {
        console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
    });

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var ws = wsio.attach(server),
    positions = {},
    total = 0;

ws.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.id = ++total;

    socket.send(JSON.stringify(positions));

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        try {
            var pos = JSON.parse(msg);
        } catch (e) {
            return;
        }

        positions[socket.id] = pos;
        broadcast(JSON.stringify({
            type: 'position',
            pos: pos,
            id: socket.id
        }));
    });

    socket.on('close', function() {
        delete positions[socket.id];
        broadcast(JSON.stringify({
            type: 'disconnect',
            id: socket.id
        }));
    });

    function broadcast(msg) {
        for (var i = 0, l = ws.clients.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (ws.clients[i] && socket.id != ws.clients[i].id) {
                ws.clients[i].send(msg);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>WebSocket cursors</title>
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

        ws.onopen = function() {
            document.onmousemove = function(ev) {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                    x: ev.clientX,
                    y: ev.clientY
                }));
            }
        }

        ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(msg.data),
                initialized = (obj.type) ? true : false;

            if (!initialized) {
                initialized = true;
                for (var id in obj) {
                    move(id, obj[id]);
                }
            } else {
                if ('disconnect' == obj.type) {
                    remove(obj.id);
                } else {
                    move(obj.id, obj.pos);
                }
            }
        }

        function move(id, pos) {
            var cursor = document.getElementById('cursor-' + id);

            if (!cursor) {
                cursor = document.createElement('img');
                cursor.src = '/cursor.png';
                cursor.id = 'cursor-' + id;
                cursor.style.position = 'absolute';
                document.body.appendChild(cursor);
            }

            cursor.style.left = pos.x + 'px';
            cursor.style.top = pos.y + 'px';
        }

        function remove(id) {
            var cursor = document.getElementById('cursor-' + id);
            if (cursor) cursor.parentNode.removeChild(cursor);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>WebSocket cursors</h1>
</body>

</html>
```